# Expanded Container not woking Inside Column

Tags: flutter

I want the height of the green container on the left to follow the height of the row, I've been trying to change the code for 2 days but it's still an error, can anyone help?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh5ch.png)

There is my code

```
class DaftarAnySelectMultiple<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String? hintSearch;
  final List<T> data;
  final void Function(List<T> data)? onSelected;
  final bool Function(String search, T data)? onSearchFn;
  final Widget Function(T data) itemBuilder;
  final String? textButton;

  const DaftarAnySelectMultiple({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    this.hintSearch,
    this.onSelected,
    required this.data,
    this.onSearchFn,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    this.textButton,
  });

  @override
  State<DaftarAnySelectMultiple> createState() =>
      _DaftarAnySelectMultipleState<T>();
}

class _DaftarAnySelectMultipleState<T>
    extends State<DaftarAnySelectMultiple<T>> {
  TextEditingController searchC = TextEditingController();
  List<bool> isCheckedList = [];

  List<T> get displayData {
    if (searchC.text.isEmpty || widget.onSearchFn == null) return widget.data;

    List<T> willDisplay = [];

    for (var e in widget.data) {
      bool matched = widget.onSearchFn!(searchC.text, e);
      if (matched) {
        willDisplay.add(e);
      }
    }

    return willDisplay;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Mengisi isCheckedList dengan nilai false sesuai panjang displayData
    isCheckedList = List.generate(displayData.length, (index) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            HeaderBab(title: widget.title),
            if (widget.onSearchFn != null) ...[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20),
                child: CustomSearchWidget(
                  hintText: widget.hintSearch,
                  onChanged: (_) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  textEditingController: searchC,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: widget.onSearchFn == null
                    ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4)
                    : null,
                itemCount: displayData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        border: Border.all(color: primaryGreen),
                      ),
                      // constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      //     minWidth: 50, maxHeight: double.infinity),
                      margin:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4, left: 8, right: 8),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          widget.itemBuilder(displayData[index]),
                          Spacer(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: isCheckedList[index]
                                          ? primaryGreen
                                          : primaryBlue),
                                ),
                                height: 25,
                                width: 25,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: isCheckedList[index]
                                      ? const Icon(
                                          Icons.check_rounded,
                                          color: primaryGreen,
                                          size: 25,
                                        )
                                      : Container(),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isCheckedList[index] = !isCheckedList[
                                      index]; // Memilih atau tidak memilih
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomButtonPrimary(
          "SIMPAN",
          onPress: () {
            List<T> selectedMultiple = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < isCheckedList.length; i++) {
              if (isCheckedList[i]) {
                selectedMultiple.add(displayData[i]);
              }
            }
            if (widget.onSelected != null) {
              setState(() {
                widget.onSelected!(selectedMultiple);

                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print(selectedMultiple);
                }
              });
            }
            Nav.back(data: "refresh");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this   widget.itemBuilder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ocs_form/config/colors.dart';
import 'package:ocs_form/config/constants.dart';

class CustomBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.dataAny,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List dataAny;
  final int index;

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CustomBoxState createState() => _CustomBoxState();
}

class _CustomBoxState extends State<CustomBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              // constraints:
              //     BoxConstraints(minWidth: 50, maxHeight: double.infinity),
              width: 50,
              // height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    spreadRadius: -5.0,
                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${widget.dataAny[widget.index][0]}",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: black87,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 4,
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 130,
              child: Text(
                "${widget.dataAny[widget.index][1]}",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: black45,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want the height of the green container on the left to follow the height of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IntrinsicHeight to wrap row widget . the reason is get row children size info then set a constraint to row.  like this:

```
ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.green),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '1',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Abcd\n efghijk',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text(
                    'check',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```